# Referencing a field from a content type in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

Ok, so I want to write a custom PHP script that I am going to insert into a Drupal content type.

I want this PHP script to be able to pull in the information from other fields in the content type.

Basically, those fields will contain data that the PHP script will use to make a database call, and ultimately display to the end user.

Is it possible to reference a field from the current content type in PHP, inside the content type? (Obviously having the PHP code module enabled is required).

Note this is in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

I thoroughly recommend ***not*** using the PHP filter module (it introduces security holes and makes it impossible to version control your code). That said, you can get the node object (and thus it's fields) in code like this:

```
if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  $some_field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_some_field');
  // etc...
}
```

Bear in mind that method will only work when you're on the full node page.

Comment: How would you recommend pulling from a custom database if not via the PHP filter?

Comment: In a custom module, where you can at least revision your code. You could implement a block, alter the node content in `hook_node_view()`, do the same in `hook_preprocess_node()`...there are probably half a dozen different methods to do this that don't involve using the PHP filter

Comment: sadly, this needs to be done rapidly, and I don't know how to work with all of that, so it's likely I'll have to go with the poor coding solution, with an eye towards switching to a custom module in the future.